# Reorder columns in heatmap, keep topology

Tags: r, graphics, visualization, data-visualization

I've generated the following heatmap in R

[image]

using the following code.

```
heatmap(data.matrix(data), col=colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "blue"))(64), labRow=NA, Rowv=NA)
```

I would like to plot the heatmap with a different column ordering. This column ordering maintains the topology of the dendrogram, so I would like to continue to plot the dendrogram as well. The R help for the `heatmap` function mentions row and column reordering, and I have tried providing the desired column order as a vector to `heatmap`'s `Colv` argument, but this did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: I answered a similar sounding question just yesterday, although I don't understand exactly how you would "keep the topology"if you are reordering columns: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20484973/how-to-arrange-column-in-heatmap-2-based-on-a-predefined-order/20485932#20485932

Comment: @DWin yeah you can "keep the topology" or tree structure but rotate around nodes reordering columns to make it look better without actually changing the information in the plot.. or rather you can theoretically as I have no idea how to do that for the underlying `hclust` function.

Answer (score 0):

The arguments to Colv need to be an ordering passed to the reorder.dendrogram function. It will NOT produce an arbitrary ordering but will impose constraints by virtue of the column dendrogram structure. This should produce a different ordering.

```
nc <- dim(data.matrix(data)}[2]
heatmap(data.matrix(data), Colv = sample(1:nc),
        col=colorRampPalette(c("yellow", "blue"))(64), 
        labRow=NA, Rowv=NA)
```